# Watch files and folders in AIR

Tags: air

I am creating a file sync application in AIR. I want to create the handler which can watch the changes in the specified folder location like Dropbox application. Whenever any file or folder gets added,removed, modified, renamed than air application should raise the event with the event name (file/folder added, renamed etc.)

Please help about the process of folder and file watcher using Aodbe AIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FileMonitor classes [(find it here](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/03/11/monitoring-file-changes-in-adobe-air/)) to monitor the files you want to watch for changes.
Have been using that for an old project, works like a charm :-)

Comment: This is not a better way to do that as there can be hundreds of files and folders, so to monitor each file, you've to create FileMonitor object for each file. That's not a good idea.

Comment: Do you have any better solution? Have you searched for anything else on Internet for that? Because as far as I know it's the only pure Flash solution that exists out there. Monitoring hundreds of file may not be as heavy as you imply. Have you done some tests to verify that? There are no info about any requirements in term of memory usage or performances of the application here, so before flaming an answer like you did maybe you should find some arguments against it, thanks.